# Text file to a hashmap

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, hashmap

I have a text file with values in the form:

---

```
[id1] text1

[id2] text2

...
```

---

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to read this text file and write it into a hashmap in java. any pointers are appreciated.

edit: yes. i havent tried it yet. i have just been able to read the terms from the files and print it in a text file so far. i was just looking at pointers. thanks.

Comment: two questions, a) how big is your file? b) what did you try? show us your codes

Comment: @TomášZato: I recommend just Googling it. You'll get a much better answer from Google than you could possibly hope to get inside a StackOverflow comment.

Comment: Thank you. Just if anyone else wondered: It is algorythm, that assigns numbers to strings using hash princip (hashed string is address of value), alowing to map asociative arrays.

Comment: @rya11111 Actually do research before you ask a question. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You could read each line and use a regex such as:

```
"\\[(.*?)\\]\\s*(.*)"
```

Then the first group would contain the ID and the second group would contain the value.

I am not going to give code because you haven't even really tried anything yet, but you could look into the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes. (Those two names of classes are links)

Explanation of regex:

```
\\[   - open bracket (escaped)
(.*?) - capturing stuff inside the brackets
\\]   - close bracket
\\s*  - whitespace
(.*)  - everything after that (the data)
```

Comment: split with limit would do, no need for regex grouping. also in some tricky cases, your regex is not safe...

Comment: yes. i havent tried it yet. i have just been able to read the terms from the files and print it in a text file so far. i was just looking at pointers. thanks.

Comment: @rya11111 Actually do research before you ask a question. [ask]

Comment: i did do some was unsuccessful .. sorry :(

Comment: @Kent In what cases is it not safe?

Comment: alright. i will look into it more and post again. sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @rya11111 No problem :) Try the regex and if you have any problems with that, you should post another question with details on the problem and what you have tried.

Comment: @Doorknob the `.*` in [] is greedy. if the text part is `I am [tricky] part` you will get wrong id and text. see here http://fiddle.re/fqeb  (clicking java to see the result)

Answer (score 0):

if your text file is small enough to be saved in objects (e.g. hashmap), you could save. or you have to think about other solutions. for example you have a 20GiB text file.

you could split the line you read by:

```
String[] arr = line.split("(?<=])\\s+", 2)
```

then you put it in your HashMap (say yourMap) by

```
yourMap.put(arr[0], arr[1])
```

I made a small example here:

```
final String a = "[001] text here";
    final String b = "[001] text [tricky] here";
    final String c = "[0 0 1] text here";

    final String regex = "(?<=])\\s+";

    // if you want to test it, you would see key/value are correctly splited
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.split(regex, 2)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b.split(regex, 2)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.split(regex, 2)));

//--------------------------------------    

//here is the part to put them into your file
    HashMap<String,String> yourMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String[] array = null;
    //for each line from that file {
    array = line.split(regex,2);
    yourMap.put(array[0], array[1]);
    //}for loop ends
```